# Reverse engineering an aggregate into a simple for loop

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me change this code back to a simple for loop?

```
public class sT
{
    public string[] Description { get; set; }
}

text = sT.Description.Aggregate(text, (current, description) =>
            current + ("<option value=" + string.Format("{0:00}", j) + "'>" + j++ + ". " + description+ "</option>"));
```

The code goes through the elements of an array "Description" and creates a list of options. I would like to do some different processing but I am not sure how to reverse engineer this. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: you mean, rewrite, not reverse engineer. Also, classic case of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); Why don't you tell us _what different processing_ you need to do?

Comment: the value to the `value` attribute misses the opening quote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate simply loops through the items of the list and passes the result of the delegate to the next call to the delegate.

The first parameter specifies the initial value to start with.

```
foreach ( string description in sT.Description )
{
    text += "<option value=" + string.Format("{0:00}", j) + "'>" + j++ + ". " + description+ "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var description in sT.Description)
{
    text += String.Format("<option value={0:00}'>{1}.{2}</option>",
                           j, 
                           j++, 
                           description)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this

```
foreach (string s in sT.Description)
            text = text + ("<option value=" + string.Format("{0:00}", j) + "'>" + j++ + ". " + s + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest

```
foreach (string s in sT.Description)
    text += string.Format("<option value='{0:00}'>{1}. {2}</option>", j, j++, s);
```

Or, rather:

```
text += sT.Description.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
        (a,s) => a.AppendFormat("<option value='{0:00}'>{1}. {2}</option>", j, j++, s)
    ).ToString();
```

I think it is clearer, and certainly more efficient. However, if you insist on having a loop for this, you can use:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string s in sT.Description)
    sb.AppendFormat("<option value='{0:00}'>{1}. {2}</option>", j, j++, s);

text += sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this

```
.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
            (a, b) => a.Append(", " + b.ToString()),
            (a) => a.Remove(0, 2).ToString());
```

Or

```
public static String Aggregate(this IEnumerable<String> source, Func<String, String, String> fn)        
{            
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (String s in source)  
     {                
         if (sb.Length > 0)                
             sb.Append(", ");              
         sb.Append(s);           
     }             
     return sb.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: you can, but it has no relation to the question. This looks like a very poorly done duplication of `string.Join` to me. Also, do you indent your code like this in real life?

Comment: It's not for me to decide the technical accuracy or correctness of an answer, however, in future please don't leave a code sample in an unformatted mess like that again. Next time it will be removed or you may find yourself suspended for low quality contributions. You can find out more about how to use the markdown editor here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help